# What's the different between *p++,* ++p,++*p in C language pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning the basic knowledge of c programming language. And now I am confused at pointer sections.
There is the original question in the book:

Array a has some value and pointer p is now at a[1]:

```
a[0]:10
a[1]:20  <---p
a[2]:30
a[3]:40
a[4]:50
```

**Question List**:

1. What's the value of `*p` after executes `* p++`?
2. What's the value of `* ++p`?
3. What's the value of `++ * p`?

So, What's the different between `*p++`, `* ++p`, `++*p`?

In my opinion:

1. `*p++` means to move pointer `p` points the next element, so the 1st answer is 30.
2. The difference of `*p++` and `*++p` just like the difference of `i++` and `++i`. so the 2nd answer is 30.
3. `*p` means the value of pointer p, so `++*p` means to let `p` value increase 1. So the 3rd answer is 21;

Am i right?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but the question is perhaps badly-worded: if the statement is `int q = *p++;`, `p`, as you say, is now pointing to `30`, but `q` equals `20`. `int q = *++p;` results in `p` pointing to `30`, and `q` also equals `30`.

Comment: You can have a good idea by trying it yourself with your preferred compiler.

Comment: Are the questions supposed to be independent from the same start; or do you do 1, then 2, then 3?

Comment: @M.M:  these 3 questions are from the same start -- possibly... the book have not describe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the value of *p after executes * p++?

`*p++` first dereferences the pointer p and then increments the pointer p. So the next call to *p will return 30.

> What's the value of * ++p?

Consider the following example:

```
int array[] = {10, 20, 30};
int * p = array;
```

In this case, * ++p will print 20. First the pointer will be incremented meaning that it will start pointing to the second element. Then it will be dereferenced.

> What's the value of ++ * p?

Consider the following example:

```
int array[] = {10, 20, 30};
int * p = array;
```

Here ++ *p will print 11. First the pointer will be dereferenced returning 10 which then will be incremented by 1 to return 11.